# Push Notifications Issue in iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, ios, xcode, push-notification

OKay..so I followed this tutorial on RayWenderlich.com about setting up push notifications in an app. It worked fine for the 1st week or so. The notifications were delivered and all was cool until today, when notifications stopped working. I repeated the steps mentioned on the site by creating a new SSL certificate, a new provisioning profile, etc but it still doesn't work. The Settings and all in my iPhone are set to receive notifications in the App.

I tried sending myself notifications from other services like FB, twitter, etc and they're all working. Can anyone temme what might not be working.

Oh and btw, my PHP code shows no error. In fact, it says that the message was successfully delivered.

I'm running out of time and help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

device token may be changed. update device token and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct mode i.e. you have enabled the push notification in development mode and install the app with the same provision profile and keep the developmental .pem file on server. If you change from development to release you need to change the .pem file from server and also remove sandbox while sending the push notification in live version.

Comment: its in development mode..i've verified it after u posted it in comment. And i've CodeSigned with the same provisioning profile..It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Apple do not guarantee that message will be delivered 100%.

Next time, don't worry so much.